# Curvas de densidade estimada por um modelo em gamlss

Tags: r, modelagem, gráfico, plot, regressão

Estou interessado em realizar um histograma da variável resposta com a densidade estimada de dois modelos de regressão ajustado pelo pacote `gamlss`.

A ideia consiste em se obter um gráfico "próximo" ao exemplo que está sendo apresentado abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, como já foi descrito, o meu interesse é realizar o traço da densidade estimada por meio dos modelos de regressão ajustado com diferentes distribuições para a variável resposta. Neste fórum, encontra-se inúmeros exemplos considerando simplesmente o traçado para checar a aderência da distribuição e/ou exemplos quando o modelo de regressão não contém covariáveis.

Abaixo encontra-se a rotina computacional de minha tentativa.

```
library(gamlss)
head(Orange)
mod1 = gamlss(circumference ~ age, 
       family=NO, data = Orange)
mod2 = gamlss(circumference ~ age, 
       family=GA, data = Orange)
x11()
hist(Orange$circumference)
lines(predict(mod1))
lines(predict(mod2))
```

Todavia, não estou obtendo sucesso na construção de tal gráfico.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução é traçar os gráficos das densidades dos valores previstos e não esses valores.

Em relação à distribuição Gama, o `gamlss`, função `GA`, ajusta um modelo logarítmico para os parâmetros `mu` e `sigma` e portanto deve-se calcular a densidade da exponencial dos valores previstos. De `help("GA")`:

> mu.link
> Defines the mu.link, with "log" link as the default for the mu parameter, other links are "inverse", "identity" ans "own"

> sigma.link
> Defines the sigma.link, with "log" link as the default for the sigma parameter, other link is the "inverse", "identity" and "own"

Tradução Google.

> mu.link
> Define o mu.link, com o link "log" como padrão para o parâmetro mu, outros links são "inverse", "identity" e "own"

> sigma.link
> Define o sigma.link, com o link "log" como padrão para o parâmetro sigma, outro link é o "inverse", "identity" e "own"

```
library(gamlss)
data(Orange)

mod1 = gamlss(circumference ~ age, 
              family=NO, data = Orange)
mod2 = gamlss(circumference ~ age, 
              family=GA, data = Orange)

ymod1 <- predict(mod1)
ymod2 <- predict(mod2)
dens1 <- density(ymod1)
dens2 <- density(exp(ymod2))

x11()
hist(Orange$circumference, freq = FALSE)
lines(dens1, lty = "dotted")
lines(dens2, lty = "dashed")
legend(x = "topright", legend = c("Normal", "Gamma"), lty = c("dotted", "dashed"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Rui.
Como eu poderia realizar o gráfico considerando a densidade AJUSTADA das distribuições de probabilidade consideradas?
A sua ajuda consiste num traçado empírico, certo? Visto que a distribuição normal ou gama não possuem forma bimodal em sua densidade.
Como eu poderia neste mesmo exemplo colocar a densidade destas distribuições no histograma utilizando os parâmetros estimados?
Se for necessário, posso fazer um outro post.